# Trying to get this website get out of beta

Tags: discussion, beta-progress, unanswered-questions

The [questions under unanswered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/unanswered) contains questions which may or may not have answers. The only **common factor** in them is that there are no upvoted answers.

I was trying to improve the percentage of answered questions on the website by going through the unanswered questions and upvoting/answering questions where appropriate.

I am having trouble finding the unanswered questions which have answers(yeah unanswered questions with answers) with no upvotes. I am trying to improve this ratio because it is needed for this website to go live and I want it to go live.

The current question to answer ratio is 1.69(14800/8722). It is showing up as 1.9 on Area 51 so maybe they don't consider the `on - hold` questions. Still that means we need to answer questions even if there are answers already present. Maybe make a habit of not accepting answers too fast?

Also is anyone interested in doing the same? I don't have expertise in Java, C++, Scala etc. but I saw many unanswered questions who had answers but I had no idea which are good answers.

Any thoughts on this?

---

Found out that [websites don't come out of beta solely on Area51 stats](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/317).

---

Found [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

Comment: Why are you so eager to get out of beta?

Comment: @Lstor I am learning to code and getting them reviewed has helped me improve a lot. So I like this website and don't want it to be taken down like they say that beta websites can be taken down. As simple as that.

Comment: I see. With 25k users and having been active for several years, I doubt CodeReview will suddenly be taken down. I think, however, that our efforts are better spent at making the community excellent for its own sake, rather than to get the site out of beta.

Comment: @Lstor That does matter but it doesn't hurt to give it some time? As far as I know a website would be taken down if its statistics get too bad. On Area51 only 2 statistics are not enough - answers/question and answered question percentage. Adding answers/upvoting answers when appropriate doesn't hurt anyone but might be helpful.

Comment: @Lstor: If it even matters, I am curious as to what CR would look like as its own site. :-) On the other hand, that would cause the privilege requirements to go up, and I assume beta users won't be "grandfathered" in.  Overall, I just want this site to prosper-- I too like this site and want to keep doing my part.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, increasing the amount of questions that have good answers is a good thing. I just don't think gaming the stats with the specific goal of getting the site out of Beta is necessarily a good idea.

Comment: @AseemBansal: It does appear that answers are the only "okays" we have, which are fortunately pretty close to the "excellent" level.  I do remember seeing the answer rate momentarily at 90%, though.  I'm not fit to answer too many of the unanswered C++ questions, but I did vote responsibly (and still am).

Comment: @AseemBansal I just joined this site, and went to the oldest question and thought hmm why is this still in beta, then saw your bulletin.. on it ;)

Comment: @AseemBansal I have just posted one question and two answers.. to one answer you left a positive comment, but have not voted on any of these posts, perhaps, if you get in the habit of voting people for useful posts, this will help encourage users to come back and help the stats

Comment: @Skippy I did actually vote on 1 answer. The other answer came after I left the site for a while. But I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for contributing!

In the search box, type:

- `answers:1` for [questions with at least one answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A1)
- `answers:0` for [questions with no answers at all](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0)

You can click "Advanced Search Tips" next to the [search box](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search) to show other useful searching syntax.

Comment: Actually these options give answers from all questions. Doesn't work for specifically unanswered questions. I'll try google search.

Comment: Can this question be made community wiki to discuss current needs to get the website out of beta? Is that allowed? Because I want to ask a bunch of other questions mainly for community-attention and don't know any other effective way except a question. It will be a waste if there are many questions each of which alone doesn't get much attention.

Comment: @AseemBansal: If it helps (in the meantime at least), this question is now on the main page's Community Bulletin.

Comment: @AseemBansal To use the search suggestion do something like this: `java answers:0`

Comment: @JonnySooter Maybe my wording in the question was faulty. I think I have corrected that.

Answer (score 4):

Great plan!

I was sort of discouraged from doing that since they haven't received enough attention. When I think about it now, that's exactly why I should start giving them some attention. When I have the time, I'll comb through the C++ questions.

I too am trying my hardest to get us out of beta. ;-)

Comment: Many reviews/efficiency questions are answered on SO even before I can suggest migrations. If they are migrated before they are answered there will be more users here and hence more views. Don't know how to do that exactly but still thinking.

Answer (score 3):

To find posts with zero voted answers, I believe target zero voted questions. A downvoted question will have received attention, and so will the answers, zero votes is the most likely group to find posts with least attention and, hence, zero voted answers. 
This is not hard and fast, but will assist.

[Questions with high votes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/is-it-better-practice-to-return-if-false-or-execute-an-if-statement-if-true), frequently have answers with high votes.

[Questions with zero votes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21214/using-a-function-to-find-the-average-for-number-of-letters-and-words), are less likely to have upvoted answers.

Using [@codesparkles suggestion](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/773/27892) of advanced searching.

Sort posts by votes.  View 50 to a page for expediency.

Go to the last page. Then pop back a few.

[image: page]

This will be a good place to start. If the answers are upvoted and the questions are not upvoted, obviously, this start point will need to be shifted.

**edit**

Just used my daily quota of votes and using my method of targeting questions with zero votes, 2/3 of the posts I went to had zero voted answers (not anymore).. I also voted the questions, to remove them from that group.

Comment: :D Thanks I'll use this method. But you aren't doing arbitrary voting, are you?

Comment: not a detailed read, but looking at effort of question or answer, especially for short answers,. there was one short answer, Like two sentences, but it answered the question, I should add, I upvote questions easily, on effort, even though they might seem silly, I look at the effor the person has made.. sorry got to go, studying nice to meet u will be back ;)